# Split date into parts - PHP/Laravel/Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, split, php-carbon

I'm starting to integrate `carbon` into my website and can't seem to be able to get the format it wants.

```
Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz);

// initial data
$day = 'today';
$time = '1100';

// i then convert them
$d = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($day));
$t = date('H:i:s',strtotime($time));

// this is what I end up with
date = "2016-01-05"
time":"11:00:00"
```

How can I split them with `php` to help me extract `$year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second`

Comment: so you want `2016`, `01`, and `05` in its own variable? and same with each individual time portion? all from the `$d` and `$t` variable?

Comment: Yes correct, thats what I want

Comment: A function will be great to handle `date` and another to handle `time` @DerekPollard

Comment: `$d= explode('-', $d);
$month = $d[0];
$day   =$d[1];
$year  = $d2];`  use same for time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the comments:

```
function convertTime($day, $time){
      $d = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s',strtotime($day." +".$time));

      $expD = explode("-", $d);

      $Year = $expD[0];
      $Month = $expD[1];
      $Day   = $expD[2];
      $Hour  = $expD[3];
      $Minute = $expD[4];
      $Second = $expD[5];

      return array($Year, $Month, $Day, $Hour, $Minute, $Second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$day = date("d");
$time = date("H:i:s")
$fulldate =  $year .'-'. $month .'-'. $day
```

That pretty much shows how you to do all of it.